# Is an orthogonal projection of a Lipschitz domain still a Lipschitz domain?

Tags: real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry

Let $\mathcal{X}\subseteq\mathbf{R}^n$ be a Lipschitz domain, i.e., for each $x\in\partial\mathcal{X}$, there exists a radius $r_x>0$ and a Lipschitz continuous function $F^x:\mathbf{R}^{n-1}\to\mathbf{R}$ such that (up to rotations and relabeling of coordinates) $$\mathcal{X}\cap B_{r_x}(x) = \lbrace x'\in\mathbf{R}^n | F^x(x_1',\ldots,x_{n-1}') < x_n' \rbrace \cap B_{r_x}(x).$$

Additionally, let $W\in\mathbf{R}^{n\times k}$, $2 < k < n$, be a matrix with orthogonal columns and define $$\mathcal{Y} := W^\top\mathcal{X} = \lbrace W^\top x | x\in\mathcal{X} \rbrace.$$

That is, $\mathcal{Y}$ denotes a orthogonal projection of $\mathcal{X}$.

Q: Is $\mathcal{Y}$ again a Lipschitz domain?

I would be very thankful not only for explanations, but also for references.

Comment: No, even if the functions $F^x$ are all 1-Lipschitz, the projection may well create inner directed cusps, so that there can't be room for outer cones. However, the *inner* cone property still holds for the projected domain.

Comment: Thank you very much! Especially, for the hint referring to the inner cone property!

Comment: An explicit counter-example is a curved croissant viewed at an angle at which its tips appear to touch each other. One more comment: mind that "Lipschitz" is striclty stronger than "inner + outer cone property".

Comment: @PietroMajer: I am wondering if also the _uniform_ inner cone property still holds for the projected domain?!

Comment: I'd say that if X is such that at any point of its boundary you can point an inner cone which is an isometric copy of a given cone $C_0$, then  so does Y:=P(X), for P a linear projector, wrto the cone $P( C_0)$. Since P is an open map, if y is a point on the boundary of Y=P(X), then y=P(x), x in the boundary of X. There is a cone C⊂X pointed at x, so P( C) ⊂ P(X) is a cone pointed at y. The only thing is that these projected cones may not vary continuously wrto y, because close points y may come from points on X far to each other

Comment: @PietroMajer Fortunately, I do not need continuity of the projected cones. It is sufficient that the projected domain satisfies again the uniform interior cone condition wrto the cone $P(C_0)$. Thanks for your elaboration!